# Set with an open cover with Lebesgue Number equal to zero.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Can someone give me an example of a set in a metric space with an open cover which has Lebesgue number = 0?

Thanks

Comment: Anything that is not compact has a good chance. The open interval $(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an easy example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick the metric space $X=\{1/n\,:\,n\in\Bbb N\setminus \{0\}\}$ with the distance $\left\lvert \frac1n-\frac1m\right\rvert$, and the open cover $\mathcal U$ of singletons. For any $\delta>0$, there is a subset of two elements which has diameter $<\delta$ (say, in the form $\left\{\frac1n,\frac1{n+1}\right\}$). Obviously, it is not contained in any singleton.